# Why is the output so messed up even tho i use threading.Lock()?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

```
import threading
import time

class Zaehler(threading.Thread):
    einaus = threading.Lock()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = 1
    def run(self):
        for a in range(10):
            #Critical Section
            with Zaehler.einaus:
                self.count += a
                print(self.count)
            #Critical Section
  


meine_threads = []
thread = Zaehler()
thread2 = Zaehler()
#thread3 = Zaehler()
meine_threads.append(thread)
meine_threads.append(thread2)
#meine_threads.append(thread3)
thread.start()
thread2.start()
#thread3.start()


for t in meine_threads:
    t.join()


OUTPUT: 
1
2
4
7
11
16
22
29
37
46
1
2
4
7
11
16
22
29
37
46

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This program has only one goal. To understand Locking() :). The variable count is the shared resource which the threads are outputing after the counted the variable up. But instead of giving ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ....) I get the output (1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22 )

Answer (score 0):

The lock is working fine, the issue is in the loop. Try a simple code without threads

```
count = 1
for a in range(10):
    x += a
    print(count)
```

this will print the same output, since you increase `count` by `a` in every iteration

```
1
2
4
7
11
16
22
29
37
46
```

To get the output as `1, 2, 3, 4...` you can do something like this for example

```
count = 0
for a in range(10):
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the line `self.count += a`. You're not incrementing the value by 1, but by the current index. So the first iteration is `count + 1` with count equals to 1, then `count + 2` with count equals to 2 (because you changed it in the previous iteration), ... Simply use a `self.count += 1`.

The second thing is that your `count` variable is not static, that means that each instance of the object gets its own variables, local to the current object, that's why the second object starts at 1 again. If you want it to be global to all instances, just declare it outside any method (like you did for the lock)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but it seems that you add **a** to count instead of **1** each time

```py
self.count += a  
# should be self.count += 1
```